# Insert value based on drop down list from cell next to matched one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sample table (B2:C4) with a couple of defined values "XXX = 10, YYY = 20, ZZZ = 30".

I have the second table (E2:F10) with drop down list in the column "E".

I need to copy value based on drop down list to column "F". It means for example when I select E3 = "XXX" from drop down list it copies appropriate value from column "C". In the example on the attached picture B1 = "XXX" -> C1 = "10" so the value will be copied to F3).

The problem is that the drop down list includes also another items than in the column "B2:B4" so I can customize the entry in the table.

I created working code but the issue is when I change any value in the column C2:C4 the value in the column F2:F10 does not change.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Res As Variant
   If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E10")) Is Nothing Then
      Res = Evaluate("INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",B2:B4,0))")
      If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
   End If
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Table PrtScn]

[Sample XLSM file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkPwtbPhqBZrkcZoNJ5_20NXHe5BpQ?e=yfOGwB)

This is how I edited the sample table and the code according @Variatus:

[image: Edited sample pictrue]

The module code:

```
Enum Nws                    ' worksheet where 'Data' values are used
    ' 060
    NwsFirstDataRow = 7     ' change to suit
    NwsTrigger = 6          ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    NwsTarget = 8              ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta                    ' columns of range 'Data'
    ' 060
    NtaId = 1
    NtaVal = 3
End Enum
```

And the sheet code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ' 060
        
        Dim Ws          As Worksheet        ' the sheet on which the "Data" range resides
        Dim Rng         As Range
        Dim Tmp         As Variant
        
        ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                        Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")    ' change to match your facts
            Set Rng = Ws.Range("B2:D4")             ' change to match your facts
            With Application
                Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Rng, 3, False)
                If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                    .EnableEvents = False   ' suppress 'Change' event
                    Cells(Target.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Tmp
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
        
        ' skip action if more than one cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then
        UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Value
    End If
        
        
    End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data' category (2 cells as Nta)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("B2:D4")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub



Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Set TgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to match your facts
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With TgtWs
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        With Rng
             Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, NtaId), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
             If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                FirstFound = Fnd.Row
                Do
                    TgtWs.Cells(Fnd.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Cat(1, NtaVal)
                    Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                    If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Immediate Window, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter. Does the code still not fire?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I already tried that before with no change.

Comment: It doesn't change because you're returning the result in the adjacent cell in column F and not the adding the formula

Comment: Also be aware that when you're using the `on change` event it's better to turn off the events so it doesn't fire twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below differs from the selected answer in the following respects.

1. All the action now takes place on one sheet, as per your original question. Therefore all the code must now be placed in one location, on the code sheet of the worksheet on which everything transpires. In consequence thereof all worksheet specification could be removed from the code.
2. An extra column was interjected in the `Data` range of which, however, only the first and third columns are used, as identified in the Enum *Nta*.

Option Explicit

```
Enum Nws                    ' worksheet where 'Data' values are used
    ' 060-2
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2     ' change to suit
    NwsTrigger = 5          ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    NwsTarget               ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta                    ' columns of range 'Data'
    ' 060
    NtaId = 1               ' 1st column of 'Data' range
    NtaVal = 3              ' 3rd column of 'Data' range
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    
    ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Range("Data"), NtaVal, False)
            If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                .EnableEvents = False       ' suppress 'Change' event
                Cells(Target.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Tmp
                .EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    Else
        Set Rng = Range("Data")             ' change to suit
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then
            UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, NtaVal).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub Worksheet_activate()
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data' category (2 cells as Nta)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = Sheet1                      ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("Data")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                     Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
    With Rng
         Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, NtaId), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
         If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = Fnd.Row
            Do
                Cells(Fnd.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Cat(1, NtaVal)
                Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like charm. I have to go deeply to your code to understand what's going on otherwise your effort won't make sense for me ;-) I do hope it will be useful for somebody else.

Comment: I went through the code and I think I understand that. But I would like to ask you for advise. I was playing around to try more scenarios to understand the logic. When I put formulas to column "D" instead of values. What would be the best way. Should I use temporary cell range with formulas and write a code to copy calculated value from temporary range to the column "D"?

Comment: @Nuficek I want to shut down this thread. It's breaking all forum rules. Please ask a new question. And ... no. I think it's conceptually wrong to place formulas in column D. Column D is designed to contain constants. The code responds to the change of those constants and updates dependants. If the constants become variables the updating system won't work anymore. So, you would have to design another system.

Comment: No problem, of course we can close the thread. That was just I wanted to understand how it works and not just copy your code. Thanks a lot again for your effort you put to this question!

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I figure out how to easy do that but when I replicated your code to the new Sheet it stopped working in that way. I think I'm missing something so I asked new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861373/how-to-calculate-formula-and-insert-value-to-respective-cell-using-change-event

Answer (score 0):

My answer could be improved if you use [Excel Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

Also some parts of the code could be refactored. For example you should add some error handling.

But, this should get you started:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim watchRange As Range
    
    Dim cellFormula As String
    
    ' Define the watched range
    Set watchRange = Me.Range("E2:E10")
       
    ' Do this for each cell changed in target
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
               
        ' Check if cell is in watched range
        If Not Intersect(cell, watchRange) Is Nothing Then
            
            cellFormula = "=INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",B2:B4,0))"
            
            ' Check if formula doesn't return an error (this could be imporoved?)
            If Not IsError(cellFormula) Then
                ' Don't fire the change event twice
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                cell.Offset(, 1).Formula = cellFormula
                Application.EnableEvents = False
            End If
            
        End If
   
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Let me know if this is what you needed and if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it works just once. As soon as I change any value the code is stopped. When I enable events it works. But the problem is that it copies the formula, not the value. So when I select any other item which doesn't match to "B2:B4" it copies (write) the formula to column "F" anyway. But it's an interesting different angle o view.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to maintain a permanent link between your table B2:C4 and the results in column F you need to establish a robust system for updating changes. In effect, column F must not only change with the selection in column E but also with updates in column C. Presuming that these data are on different sheets in your project different worksheet events must be captured and coordinated. To be safe you should also update all occasionally, such as on Workbook_Open or Worksheet_Activate in case an update was missed due to a system crash.

None of that is particularly difficult to program but Excel offers a solution without VBA that is so stunningly better that it can't be ignored. Here it is.

1. Create a named range C2:C4. I called it "Data" and made it dynamic so that it can expand without requiring my attention.
2. Use the first column of this range to feed the data validation drop-down: `=INDEX(Data,,1)`
3. Use this formula in column F, `=VLOOKUP(E2,Data,2,FALSE)`

All conditions laid out above are met.

Comment: The problem is that I need the column "F" to be overwritten which I probably didn't mention exactly. So I would be able to make custom entry in the column "F". That's why I have to solve it via VBA. I would love to stick with formulas only as it's much more easier for me and I'm advanced user against VBA where I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

As promised above, the VBA solution is a lot more complicated than the one with VLOOKUP. But you can start in the same way. Create a named range where you store your "Categories" as I came to call them after I named the range "Data". This is a range with 2 columns, exactly as B2:C4 in your example. You can have this range on the same sheet as the action but I programmed in the assumption that it would be on another sheet.

Next, please install these enumerations in a standard code module. The first Enum identifies parts of the worksheet on which the range E:F of your example resides. It specifies row 2 as the first row with data, meaning row 1 will be omitted from scrutiny, and, in fact, assigns the job of columns 5 and 6, (E and F) of your example to the same columns in my code's output. You can change all of these values. The second enum identifies the columns of the 'Data' range. Naming these columns helps read the code. Changing the numbers makes no sense.

```
Enum Nws                    ' worksheet where 'Data' values are used
    ' 060
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2     ' change to suit
    NwsTrigger = 5          ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    NwsTarget               ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta                    ' columns of range 'Data'
    ' 060
    NtaId = 1
    NtaVal
End Enum
```

The code below must be pasted to the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the Data Validation drop-down. That is the one holding columns E:F of your example. Don't paste this code in the same module as the enumerations or any other standard code module. It must be the module assigned to the worksheet with these data. The code will check if an entry made in column E is present in 'Data' and get the value from there if it is. Else it will do nothing. Observe that this code needs to know where the category data are, worksheet and range name. I've marked the lines where you can change the specs.

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ' 060
        
        Dim Ws          As Worksheet        ' the sheet on which the "Data" range resides
        Dim Rng         As Range
        Dim Tmp         As Variant
        
        ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                        Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Set Ws = Sheet1                 ' change to match your facts
            Set Rng = Ws.Range("Data")      ' change to match your facts
            With Application
                Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Rng, 2, False)
                If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                    .EnableEvents = False   ' suppress 'Change' event
                    Cells(Target.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Tmp
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

Finally, there is code to go into the worksheet on which you have the category data (B2:C4 in your example). This, too, must be the code sheet attached to that worksheet, *not* a standard code module. There is a procedure called `Worksheet_Change` which is the same as a corresponding procedure for the other sheet. Since there can't be two procedures of the same name in the same module these two procedures would have to be merged if you eventually need both the 'Data' and the validations on the same worksheet as you have them in your example. The code is laid out to have them on separate sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data' category (2 cells as Nta)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = Sheet2                      ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("Data")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 060
    
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet            ' the Tab on which 'Data' resides
    Dim Rng         As Range
    
    ' skip action if more than one cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set Ws = Sheet1                         ' change to suit
    Set Rng = Ws.Range("Data")              ' change to suit
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then
        UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, NtaVal).Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Set TgtWs = Sheet2                      ' change to match your facts
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With TgtWs
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        With Rng
             Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, NtaId), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
             If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                FirstFound = Fnd.Row
                Do
                    TgtWs.Cells(Fnd.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Cat(1, NtaVal)
                    Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                    If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

These three procedures work to maintain synch between the categories and the data, meaning, if a change occurs in the categories the data should reflect them. The key to this is the procedure `UpdateCategory` which looks for the category name in the data and ensures that it's the same as in the categories table. This procedure is called in two different ways.

One is when the value of a category is changed. It will then update that particular category. The other I have timed with the deactivation event of the worksheet. At that time *all* categories are updated, just in case an individual update has failed earlier. If you have a lot of data, or a lot of categories, this may prove slow. If so, there are ways to make it work faster.

I draw your attention to the need to specify both worksheets and the name of the 'Data' range in these procedures as well. The locations are marked. Please look for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code. It's more complicated than I expected :-) I don't want to just copy your code and use it but rather I would like to understand what's going on inside. So I would like to ask you where is defined checking of any change in the columns "C" and "F". So let's say I would like to move the column "C" to "D" (column #4) and column "F" to column "I" (column #9). If I understand I have to change "NwsTarget = 9" (for column "I" and NtaVal = 4 (for column "D"). Is that correct?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes. There are 2 distinct processes. (1) Keep F synched with C and (2) keep C synched with F. For one you need to watch for changes in E, for the other you watch for changes in C. These two watches are carried out by the Worksheet_Change event procedures. They act when a change occurs in their respective areas. However, each of their actions, though separate and independent, affect the other's area. Therefore the definition of of locations is centralized in the enumerations which both of them use jointly.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It's really smart. I understood that the same way. 
But when I change "NtaId = 1  NtaVal = 4 "  and then change any value in in column "D" nothing happens. 
Changing "NwsFirstDataRow = 7  NwsTrigger = 6  NwsTarget = 8" works with no problem. 
So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: btw if I understand correctly "NtaId = 1" means the first column in the range "data", right?

Comment: Correct. An enum (enumuration) is an efficient way to assign names to numbers. `xlUp` is an enum, or `xlDown`, and I build my names on a similar pattern. 'Nta' is the "family name". All names in this group have that prefix. `Id` and `Val` are the proper names which are descriptive of their meaning.

Comment: So then I don't understand why it doesn't work. I just shifted column "C" and "F" by one position to the right to understand behavior. So I changed the code as I mentioned above.

Comment: The 'Data' range isn't set by the code. The code presumes it to be a 2-column range which you set from Excel's user interface (its worksheet). NtaId is the first column, NtaVal the second. The enum Nta makes no statement about where these columns are in the workbook or on a worksheet. In my solution I recommended not to change these values because change can't be made to make sense. You can move the range from Excel's UI to the location of your choice requiring no change to any part of the code. The range's first column will always be its first and, therefore, NtaId (= 1)

Comment: I'm a bit lost now. So if I extend the data range to 3 columns and the checking values will be now in the third one what do I need to change? First column "Ntald" is clear but what about the third one?

Comment: Well, haha, that's what the names are for (so that we don't have to discuss the meaning "checking values"). If the *Value* is in column 3 now then `NtaVal` should be 3. On the other hand, if the *Id* is in the 3rd column then `NtaId` must have the value of 3. The *Id* is the, ah mmp, value that's used in the drop-down.

Comment: So if I understand correctly "NtaId" would be always the first column of 'data range' (table) and "NtaVal" always the last column no matter how large is the table. So if for example "Data" would be in the range "C2:G10" so NatId would tlbe always "1" as the first column and "NatVal" would be the last one so "5". No matter what is between. Just the first and the last column, correct?

Comment: Wrong. There are 5 columns in the range C2:G10. Number them from 1 to 5 so that C is 1 and G is 5. Then use that number to identify the Id and Val columns. If you have the Id in column 3 and the Value in column 5 then NtaId should be 3 and NtaVal = 5.

Comment: So then I understand it correctly. Could you check my file what is wrong or what I'm missing, please?
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkPwtbPhqBZrkcZoNJ5_20NXHe5BpQ?e=JXY8fJ

Comment: I edited my question and added your code which I tried to edit according attached table print screen. It would be more transparent and useful for other users. If you can check it and let me know what I'm doing wrong it would be great.

Comment: I have a problem with Google, or maybe Windows, which insists on giving me a Chinese user interface for your workbook. I can't find the button to download your file. Nor will I go through the code in your question line by line to find what you have changed. Your first step should be to create a workbook exactly like the one you originally published but having the two tables on different worksheets. My code will run. Don't make changes to the layout until after the code runs. Then, when you still have a problem, say what the problem is, where it occurs and how it makes itself known.

Comment: It's strange as I use US version of Windows, Office and OneDrive. But there is a PrtScn of this table in my answer. What I basically did was just moving data from column "C" to "D" (extend the Data range and make one empty column in between). And then I had to move the other table by one column and I also inserted one empty column in between. I fully understand what's going on when I select anything from the dropdown list so even when I moved extend the table it works perfectly. But I do not exactly understand how to tell the code that it must checking column "D" instead of  "C".

Comment: It isn't your system. It's mine but that's what I have. This project doesn't know columns C and D. It knows the 'Data' range and columns 1 & 2 in that range, aka NtaId and NtaVal. If 'Data' now has 3 columns and the value is in column 3 then NtaVal = 3, and that's that. Focus on the other table. There you have a *Trigger* column and a *Target* column., originally E and F (5 and 6), identified as NwsTrigger and NwsTarget. If you inserted a column between them they are no longer consecutive and you must assign the correct value to the latter, `NwsTarget = 7`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. Then I understand that correctly and it just doesn't work as I described above. So I don't know where is the mistake :(

Comment: I would like to explain you how it works now:
1) When I select item from dropdown list in the column "E" it correctly fills data to column "F" from column "D"
2) When I change the value in the column "D" nothing happens. But when I fill any value to column "C" it overwrite appropriate cell in the column "F". 
So it looks like that even if I designated range "B2:D4" as "Data" it still counts "NtaVal" as column "C" (the second one) instead of  "D" (the last one) against what you explained me above and how I understand that from the beginning.

Comment: Look for this code in the code module behind the tab containing the *Data* range. UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Value and replace it with `UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, NtaVal).Value`. The hard-coded "2" refers to the presumed number of columns of the *Data* range. You could simply make it "3".  If you make it "NtaVal" it will also be 3 for now but would expand if you decide to interject more columns in the future.

Comment: That's how I understand that from the very beginning. But it doesn't work. It still works only in the second column no matter what I change in "UpdateCategory". I tried both variants "NtaVal" and "3".

Comment: Let me get this straight. You did copy everything, except both tables on different sheets. And that worked for you. Then you inserted a column between B and C. The value column became column C and NtaVal = 3. You also changed the Resize instruction I told you yesterday, from "2" to "NtaVal". Now, what - exactly, doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I kept both tables on the one sheet and everything worked perfectly. 
Then I inserted a column between B and C. So now column C is empty and values are in the column D. 
Now when I select item from dropdown list in column E the value from D is correctly copied to F. But when I change value in the column D (overwrite it) nothing happens in the column F. 
But if put any value in the column C (which is now empty because I moved values to D) then it copies the value to the column F.
And it's regardless of what I change in ye "UpdateCategory" of your code.

Comment: Aah  Perfectly tested. Perfectly reported. This won't take long. Watch this space.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with my code. This is the line responsible (in the change event) `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then`. As you see it refers to column NtaVal which you changed to 3, which is column D. But you claim a response from column C which would be 2. If you can't find the mistake in **Columns(NtaVal)** replace all the code with original and just make the 2 changes we agreed. That's the version that works with me.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but I was on a business trip past 3 days and had no time for answer. I really appreciate your help to sort it out. 
So I replaced everything it with the original code and changed only one value in the line code:
`UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Value`
to
`UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, NtaVal).Value`
No matter what I put there 2, 3 or NtaVal it doesn't make any change which is very strange and I have to miss something :(

Comment: I copied your code again and changed just `Sheet2` to `Sheet1` as I have it on one sheet and still the same issue. It works in column "C" only which is really weird. Here is the link to the file if you would be able to review it: [link] https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkPwtbPhqBZrkclG7KRjMcGkVZHetg?e=MOBxTs

Comment: I now understand that you were trying to through the two Change event procedures into one which can't be done that way. But I'm reluctant to put more work into this experiment. I fear that once we have it working on one sheet you will ask to have it split again. If you assure me that the final version will have both tables on the same sheet I shall revise my answer and post code that works exactly on your sample - and no other way.

Comment: Yeah, that was my intention to keep both tables on the same sheet and nothing else. I would really appreciate if you can help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to make it simple. So here is the origin table from my answer above where I just extend Data range and values in the column "C" are now in the column "D". Everything works except when I change value in the column "D" nothing happens:

[sample table extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8JTf.png)

Module code:

```
Enum Nws                    ' worksheet where 'Data' values are used
    ' 060
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2     ' change to suit
    NwsTrigger = 5          ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    NwsTarget              ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta                    ' columns of range 'Data'
    ' 060
    NtaId = 1
    NtaVal
End Enum
```

Test sheet code:

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ' 060
        
        Dim Ws          As Worksheet        ' the sheet on which the "Data" range resides
        Dim Rng         As Range
        Dim Tmp         As Variant
        
        ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                        Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")    ' change to match your facts
            Set Rng = Ws.Range("Data")             ' change to match your facts
            With Application
                Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Rng, 3, False)
                If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                    .EnableEvents = False   ' suppress 'Change' event
                    Cells(Target.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Tmp
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
        
        ' skip action if more than one cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then
        UpdateCategory Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Value
    End If
        
        
    End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data' category (2 cells as Nta)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("Data")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub



Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Set TgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to match your facts
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With TgtWs
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
        With Rng
             Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, NtaId), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
             If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                FirstFound = Fnd.Row
                Do
                    TgtWs.Cells(Fnd.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Cat(1, NtaVal)
                    Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                    If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Variatus Here is what you asked me. I just extend the data range. The link to table print screen is attached.

Comment: Please check your copy of the Worksheet_Change event procedure. There is a major copying error. I updated the *Resize* instruction in my answer. So you can get a fresh copy of the whole procedure from there. I also have a new PC (this is its very first use after setup) and downloaded your file. In your workbook the value assigned to NtaVal is 2 (no value assigned makes it 2. Assign 3 if you want to insert a column) and the Change event procedure has the same  corruption in it as you posted above.