# How to calculate formula and insert value to respective cell using change event

Tags: excel, vba

I was asking for help with the code in the following question:

[Insert value based on drop down list from cell next to matched one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615406/insert-value-based-on-drop-down-list-from-cell-next-to-matched-one)

With a big effort of @Variatus who helped me to find the solution I have working code to "insert value based on drop down list from cell next to matched one" which works in both ways. When I was playing around to to get deep in the code I tried to figure out how to use `Worksheet_Change` for formula calculation. I wanted to avoid complex code so I'm checking column "D" with dropdown list values and when this is changed then calculated formula value in the column "E" is copied to matched cell in the next table. Everything works like a charm on my "Sheet1". But when I tried to replicate the code to my "Sheet2" it stopped working this way even I didn't change anything. Maybe I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is. I tried start over from the beginning but still nothing.

And here are two PrtScns of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2":

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

And this the code I used for Sheet1 which works with no issue:

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                    ' worksheet where 'Data' values are used
    ' 060-2
    NwsFirstDataRow = 10     ' change to suit
    NwsTrigger = 8           ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    NwsTarget = 10           ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta                    ' columns of range 'Data'
    ' 060
    NtaId = 1               ' 1st column of 'Data' range
    NtaVal = 4              ' 3rd column of 'Data' range
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    
    ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Range("Data"), NtaVal, False)
            If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                .EnableEvents = False       ' suppress 'Change' event
                Cells(Target.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Tmp
                .EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    Else
        Set Rng = Range("B2:E4")             ' change to suit
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal - 1)) Is Nothing Then
'        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D4")) Is Nothing Then
            UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, NtaVal).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub Worksheet_activate()
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data' category (2 cells as Nta)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = Sheet1                      ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("Data")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTrigger), _
                     Cells(Rows.Count, NwsTrigger).End(xlUp))
    With Rng
         Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, NtaId), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
         If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = Fnd.Row
            Do
                Cells(Fnd.Row, NwsTarget).Value = Cat(1, NtaVal)
                Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And the code for Sheet2 which doesn't:

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws1                    ' worksheet where 'Data1' values are used
    ' 060-2
    Nws1FirstData1Row = 16     ' change to suit
    Nws1Trigger = 18          ' Trigger column (5 = column E)
    Nws1Target = 20            ' Target column (no value = previous + 1)
End Enum

Enum Nta1                    ' columns of range 'Data1'
    ' 060
    Nta1Id = 1               ' 1st column of 'Data1' range
    Nta1Val = 5              ' 3rd column of 'Data1' range
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    
    ' skip action if more than 1 cell was changed
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(Nws1FirstData1Row, Nws1Trigger), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, Nws1Trigger).End(xlUp))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            Tmp = .VLookup(Target.Value, Range("Data1"), Nta1Val, False)
            If Not IsError(Tmp) Then
                .EnableEvents = False       ' suppress 'Change' event
                Cells(Target.Row, Nws1Target).Value = Tmp
                .EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    Else
        Set Rng = Range("M19:M25")             ' change to suit
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(Nta1Val - 2)) Is Nothing Then
        UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, Nta1Val).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub Worksheet_activate()
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim TgtWs           As Worksheet        ' the Tab on which 'Data1' was used
    Dim Cat             As Variant          ' 'Data1' category (2 cells as Nta1)
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Set TgtWs = Sheet2                      ' change to match your facts
    
    With Range("Data1")                      ' change to match your facts
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Cat = .Rows(R).Value
            UpdateCategory Cat
        Next R
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCategory(Cat As Variant)
    ' 060-2
    
    Dim Fnd             As Range            ' matching cell
    Dim FirstFound      As Long             ' row of first match
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(Nws1FirstData1Row, Nws1Trigger), _
                     Cells(Rows.Count, Nws1Trigger).End(xlUp))
    With Rng
         Set Fnd = .Find(Cat(1, Nta1Id), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
         If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = Fnd.Row
            Do
                Cells(Fnd.Row, Nws1Target).Value = Cat(1, Nta1Val)
                Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Fnd.Row <> FirstFound
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be well appreciated!

Comment: what is the issue with worksheet 2, any error etc.?

Comment: Please do not include external links to files with macros in them as they can be dangerous.

Comment: In the Sheet1 there is drop down list in the column range H10:H18. If you select any item from the dropdown list it's compared to the column range B2:B4 and appropriate value from the column E is inserted to column J. This works with no issue. But as I put formulas in the column E (there is =PRODUCT(C2,D3)) I need to watch for changes of values. So I'm checking for changes in the column D and then calculated value from column E is also changed in the column J. It also works with no issue.

Comment: So I tried to replicate the code in the second sheet which in reality is much more complex but I deleted all other codes and data just try it out. It's basically the same and the formula is in the column range O19:O25 and checking value is in the column range M19:M25. Everything works except when I change any value in the column range M19:M25.

Comment: This is looking like one of those questions where someone helped a guy by doing it for him, but then other guy can't actually figure how to adapt. The basic problem is your understanding of VBA and how variables are being used.

Comment: @Peyter You are partially right. I'm total amateur doing it just for fun. Of course I understand VBA and variables but as I'm total beginner I'm able to create just basic codes. When I asked for help with this code I haven't imagined that it would be so complex. So as I mention before if somebody put a lot of efforts in it I would like to learn it and understand that not just copy that. It's in my opinion the biggest thanks if somebody learn from it. If I want just copy the code I would ask for the direct code I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from the original code.

```
Set Rng = Range("Data")             ' change to suit
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal)) Is Nothing Then
    UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, NtaVal).Value
End If
```

Below is the corresponding part from your code behind Sheet1.

```
Set Rng = Range("B2:E4")             ' change to suit
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(NtaVal - 1)) Is Nothing Then
    UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, NtaVal).Value
End If
```

And here is the exact same part from your code behind Sheet2.

```
Set Rng = Range("M19:M25")             ' change to suit
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(Nta1Val - 2)) Is Nothing Then
UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, Nta1Val).Value
End If
```

Now you can analyse what happened.

1. The `Data` range was declared by name to relieve you of the chore to check the address multiple times. You need it on the sheet and you need it in the code. You set it once and it will be correct wherever you use the name.
2. In your own rendering of the same code you changed the name to a sheet address: `Range("B2:E4")`. It's true that it makes no difference, except that you have to check to be sure that Range("B2:E4") really is the same as `Data`. It's extra work but it works.
3. with `Set Rng = Range("M19:M25")` you walked into the trap which you set for yourself. By your design this is supposed to be the named range `Data1`. But it isn't. `Data1` has 5 columns and the range you declare in its place has only 1.

From the above analysis it's very clear by which logic you arrived at the mistake. You didn't "own" the named range. Therefore you strove to replace it with coordinates. In the process you gave up the safety that comes from using named variables and then failed to put in the extra checking needed when you take extra risk.

Please observe the missing intent for the line `UpdateCategory Cells(Target...` in your code for Sheet2. The indent serves to show the beginning and End of the IF statement. One would expect a beginner to need more of such help reading code than an expert. Truth is however that all beginners (your good-self included) think it makes no difference, and it really doesn't, but more advanced programmers know that they need clarity above all else. You can tell the experience of a programmer from the indenting he applies in his code. It's a very reliable indicator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expertise. You are right with the range I declared. And I understand your logic. I used to define range directly because when I declared it like the named range it didn't work. So I wanted to debug the mistake. So the part of the code should be: 
`Set Rng = Range("Data1")
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(Nta1Val - 2)) Is Nothing Then
                 UpdateCategory Cells(Target.Row, Rng.Column).Resize(1, Nta1Val).Value`

Comment: Where `Data1` is the range "K19:O25" and I'm checking column 3 for changes (`Nta1Val - 2`) and the final value is copied from the column 5 (`Nta1Val`) where are formulas. Is that correct?

Comment: I can't reply to you without testing, and I don't want to test. (1) `Data1` is the range of your data where 2 columns are of consequence, identified as NtaId and NtaVal. I don't know if `Data1` = K19:O25. It must not be re-declared in the code. Test with `Debug.Print Rng.Address`. (2)  NtaVal-2 identifies a column 2 steps to the left of column NtaVal. Since Nta1Val = 5, Nta1Val - 2 will not take you to Nta1Id. I don't remember why I chose NtaVal-2. Now it seems to me that it should have been straight forward `Intersect(Target, Rng.Columns(Nta1Id))`